# How to make an http request from one container to another on the same instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a multicontainer docker instance in aws beanstalk, I have 4 containers running, an nginx proxy that receives requests and forwards them to the correct microservice and 3 microservices in node that receive these requests. But now I need a microservice to call another locally, is it possible? I tried all possible configurations, I created a link between the containers, a network, but I always get the following error

**getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://user:5003**

Here are the settings of the instance

***Dockerrun.aws.json***

```js
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "auth",
      "image": "xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/auth-api",
      "hostname": "auth",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128,
      "links": [
        "profile",
        "user"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "profile",
      "image": "xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/profile-api",
      "hostname": "profile",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
    },
    {
      "name": "user",
      "image": "xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/user-api",
      "hostname": "user",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/nginx",
      "hostname": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 443,
          "containerPort": 443
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "auth",
        "profile",
        "user"
      ],
      "memory": 64
    }
  ]
}
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```js
version: "3.8"

networks:
  isolation-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx:
    image:  ********.amazonaws.com/nginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../etc/pki/tls/certs:/etc/nginx/certs  
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - isolation-network
  auth:
    image:  ********.amazonaws.com/auth-api
    build:
        context: ./auth-api
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./auth-api:/app
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
      - user
    networks:
      - isolation-network
  profile:
    image: ********.amazonaws.com/profile-api
    build:
        context: ./profile-api
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./profile-api:/app
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
    networks:
      - isolation-network
  user:
    image: ********.amazonaws.com/user-api
    build:
        context: ./user-api
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./user-api:/app
    ports:
      - "5003:5003"
    networks:
      - isolation-network
```

***Dockerfile (auth microservice)***

```js
FROM **********.amazonaws.com/node-image

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

COPY src /usr/src/app/src

RUN ls -a

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 5001

CMD [ "node", "./dist/server.js" ]
```

***Dockerfile (user microservice)***

```js
FROM ******.amazonaws.com/node-image

RUN apk update

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

COPY src /usr/src/app/src

# WORKDIR /usr/src/app/dist/uploads

RUN ls -a

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 5003

CMD [ "node", "./dist/server.js" ]
```